# getComputedStyle from the `before` pseudo element

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get the computed style from a `:before` selector of an element.

I have tried this, but it's not working, how can I make this work?

```
var a = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#one:before'), null);
alert(a.getPropertyValue("content"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/99qe4knh/5/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[According to MDN,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) the second parameter to the [`.getComputedStyle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)  is the pseudo element:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[, pseudoElt]);
```

> pseudoElt (Optional) - A string specifying the pseudo-element to match. Must be omitted (or null) for regular elements.

Therefore you should use the following:

```
var a = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#one'), ':before');

alert(a.getPropertyValue("content"));
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7z8vxt6z/)