# Get content of ::marker pseudo element

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

I am trying to get the computed style of `::marker` pseudo-selector

```
getComputedStyle(element, "::marker");
```

But how can I get `content` of the pseudo-selector? If it `"none"` or `"normal"` in computed styles, but in DOM it is `"1."`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getComputedStyle from the \`before\` pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016767/getcomputedstyle-from-the-before-pseudo-element)

Comment: @SigurdMazanti No it doesn't

Comment: If _you_ don't specify a value for the `content` property, then it will simply have the value `normal`. Doesn't matter whether it _shows_ `1` in the rendered output, the value of the property is still `normal`.

Comment: Okay, thank you @CBroe, but is it possible to get content of marker from dom?